# Prove $[0,1]$ is closed using the definition of all sequences converge to their limit points.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> **Definition:** A point **x** is a limit point of a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R^n}$ if there is a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with $a_n \in A$ such that $x = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n$
>
> **Defintion:** A subset $S \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ is closed if it contains all of its limit points

Prove that [0,1] is closed.

**Attempt:**

Since I don't have the definition of the open ball at my disposal I'm not sure how to even begin this proof. Perhaps I would let $x_n \in [0,1]$ represent a convergent sequence....

**Edit:** I also notice that the set is bounded, so perhaps I can evoke the Bolzano Weirstrauss theorem in some way...

Comment: I guess you can use Calculus: if $x_n$ is in $[0,1]$ for any $n$, then $x_n\leqslant 1$ for any $n$, so what can you say about the limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to show that $[0,1]$ contains all of its limit points. So let $x$ be a limit point of $[0,1]$. By definition, theres a sequence $(x_n)_n$ with $x_n \in [0,1]$ such that $x_n \to x$. But $x_n \geq 0$ for all $n$ then implies that $x \geq 0$. And similarly $x \leq 1$. So $x \in [0,1]$. As $x$ was arbitrary, we're done.

Comment: Surely it can't be this straightforward?.....No epsilon arguments? Nothing?

Comment: @dc3rd I suppose it depends on whether you can use the fact that $x_n \to x$ and $x_n \geq 0$ imply $x \geq 0$. If that's something that you need to prove, then some epsilons are probably in order.